# Where is the commit() defined for ember-data's currentTransaction?

Tags: ember.js

Does anyone know where the `commit()` function is defined for

```
get(this, 'currentTransaction').commit();
```

or

```
get(this, 'defaultTransaction').commit();
```

in [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L940)?

Answer (score 1):

commit() is defined in [DS.Transaction](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/transaction.js#L194).